# How to access files in USB in linux

Tags: usb, usb-drive, block-device, lsblk, lsusb

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, recently (almost a week ago) I upgraded my kernel from 5.11.0 to 5.14.0 and after that I can't access any USB drivers.
The system recognises my USBs since when I run `lsusb` it give the output

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0781:556b SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Edge
```

And even `dmesg` gives

```
[16972.246970] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[16972.395933] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=556b, bcdDevice= 1.26
[16972.395938] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[16972.395939] usb 1-2: Product: Cruzer Edge
[16972.395940] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[16972.395941] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 2005375352115C834970
```

But `lsblk` does show the device mounted anywhere this is the output of `lsblk`, in this both sda and sdb are harddrives

```
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0    16M  0 part 
└─sda2   8:2    0 931.5G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb2   8:18   0    16M  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0  80.7G  0 part 
├─sdb4   8:20   0  37.3G  0 part /
└─sdb5   8:21   0   980M  0 part
```

The USB isn't faulty because I've checked it in other laptops neither is the USB port since I've tested it in windows (I've dual booted Ubuntu with windows) in the same machine and it works well there.

I doubt that this might have happened because, while generating config files for modules and driver while upgrading to kernel 5.14.0 I used `make localmodconfig` which makes a new config file from the drivers in use at that time instead of copying the config files in the old kernel, therefore maybe the device driver maybe missing (not sure though, I don't know much about accessing block devices). If that's the case how to fix it?

Is there any way I can find the device and mount it into a directory to access the files in a USB?

Edit 1:
This is the output I get as the output for `sudo journalctl --follow`

```
Nov 29 19:25:16 adeeb kernel: usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
Nov 29 19:25:16 adeeb kernel: usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=556b, bcdDevice= 1.26
Nov 29 19:25:16 adeeb kernel: usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Nov 29 19:25:16 adeeb kernel: usb 1-2: Product: Cruzer Edge
Nov 29 19:25:16 adeeb kernel: usb 1-2: Manufacturer: SanDisk
Nov 29 19:25:16 adeeb kernel: usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 2005375352115C834970
Nov 29 19:25:16 adeeb mtp-probe[18152]: checking bus 1, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2"
Nov 29 19:25:16 adeeb mtp-probe[18152]: bus: 1, device: 8 was not an MTP device
Nov 29 19:25:16 adeeb mtp-probe[18155]: checking bus 1, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2"
Nov 29 19:25:16 adeeb mtp-probe[18155]: bus: 1, device: 8 was not an MTP device
```

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and let us hope, solve it.

Comment: I would hazard a guess and say the kernel module `usb_storage` has not been loaded, since if it was, we would see evidence of the applied scsi device name.

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl --follow` as you connect the drives to get more information. Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Please can you add `sudo parted --list` so we can see filesystem?